# How to search list of object through dictionary and return value

Tags: python, dictionary, object, search, match

```
Table_3 = 

    safety_class       factor
0          low           0.90
1       medium           0.85
2         high           0.80
3    very_high           0.75
```

My code which works for single row:

```py
def l_factor(safety_class, *args, **kwargs):
    '''This function provides longitudnal usage factor 
        based on the table 3-10'''

    table = tables['Table_3']
    value_search = safety_class
    match_table_value = table[table['safety_class'].str.match(value_search)]    # returns list o
    usage_factor = match_table_value['usasge_factor']
    longitudnal_usage_factor = usage_factor
    
    return l_factor

safety_class = 'medium'
```

This code works for single row, however how do i convert this into an input of arrays ?

```
safety_class = array(['medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'high'], dtype=object)
```

How can I match these list of array objects similar to the `str.contain` --> dictionary ?

Any help is much appriciated !! Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of table3?

Comment: Your code is rather confusing as a lot of the names are rather inconsistent. match_table_value does not have a 'usasge_factor' column (unless you mean factor?), and you return l_factor at the end even though l_factor was not used anywhere in the code (unless you mean longitudnal_usage_factor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but how about

```
table = tables['Table_3']
l_factor = []
for i in safety_class:
  value_search = i
  match_table_value = table[table['safety_class'].str.match(value_search)]
  something something....
  l_factor.append(longitudnal_usage_factor)
return l_factor
```

basically use a for loop to loop through your safety_class array, adding each loop's final value into a l_factor array, and returning that array in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over a list of search strings.

Here's a minimal working example.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
d         = {'safety_class':['low','medium','high', 'very_high' ],
            'factor':[ 0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.75]}
df        = pd.DataFrame(d)
searches  = ['medium','high']
matches   = [ df['factor'][df['safety_class'].str.match(s)] for s in searches]
joined    = np.concatenate(matches)
print(joined)  
> [0.85 0.8 ]
```

I assumed you are working with pandas for creating the table, the string `'usasge_factor'` is meant to be `'factor'`, and that `longitudnal_usage_factor` is one of the matches you want to have returned by your function.

The suggested snippet uses list comprehension to iterate over you list of search strings `searches`. Note that I first extract the column `df['factor']` from the table/dataframe and thereafter the boolean index array is passed. This reduces the number of columns the indexing operation is applied to, which speeds the code up.

Some advice wrt to your code: I'd suggest to pass the table/dataframe you operate on as an argument to the function. You should also not use `*args` `**kwargs` if they are unused.

Comment: Thank your Mar, I appreciate your help.